# How to convert DB2 trigger to SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2

I am converting some DB2 triggers to SQL Server. One of them shown here I am struggling with it, Conversion tried at certain extend but seems not good enough to work out.

Trigger execute before an update or insert and selecting the value of column `PDE_KEY` based on `Select` statement in brackets with where clause before written to the database.

Need help.

DB2 trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TDC" BEFORE
INSERT
    ON
    "DECL_CONSIGNMENT" REFERENCING NEW AS NEW FOR EACH ROW NOT SECURED SET
    NEW.PDE_KEY = (
    SELECT
        D.PDE_KEY
    FROM
        DECL D
    WHERE
        D.DE_KEY = NEW.DE_KEY)
```

SQL Server conversion of this trigger (my attempt):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TDC]
ON [DECL_CONSIGNMENT]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PDE_KEY BIGINT
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT
        @PDE_KEY = D.PDE_KEY
    FROM
        DECL D
    WHERE
        D.DE_KEY = (...work upto here)
END
```

Comment: You need to also explain the logic that the trigger is attempting to implement.

Comment: Trigger execute before an update or insert and selecting the value of column `PDE_KEY` based on `Select` statement in brackets with where clause before written to the database. Hope this explain the logic.

Comment: [edit] any clarifications directly into your question.

Answer (score 1):

An `instead of` trigger must explicitly execute the dml needed.

```
REATE TRIGGER [TDC]
ON [DECL_CONSIGNMENT]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN       
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [DECL_CONSIGNMENT] (a, b, .. PDE_KEY, ..)
    SELECT a, b, .. (
       SELECT
         D.PDE_KEY
       FROM
         DECL D
       WHERE
         D.DE_KEY = i.DE_KEY),
       ..
    FROM inserted i;
END
```

Comment: Come to following script...

`CREATE TRIGGER [TDC]
ON [DECL_CONSIGNMENT]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN       
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [DECL_CONSIGNMENT] (PDE_KEY)
    SELECT PDE_KEY (
       SELECT
         D.PDE_KEY 
       FROM
         DECL D
       WHERE
         D.DE_KEY = i.DE_KEY)
    FROM inserted i;
END`

Having error.... 
`Msg 156, Level 15, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 3] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15 [Batch Start Line 3] Incorrect syntax near ')'`